# In GraphQL/Rails how to pass arguments in the query_type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphiql

So I'm trying to query on a single user within the database but end up getting:

```
"Field 'userSingle' doesn't accept argument 'first_name'"
```

I'm getting that in GraphiQL when I run the following query:

```
query GetSingleUser {
 userSingle(first_name: "Test"){
  first_name
  last_name
 }
}
```

In my query_type.rb I have the following:

```
field :userSingle, !types[Types::UserType] do
 resolve -> (obj, args, ctx) {
 argument :first_name, !types.String
 argument :id, types.ID
 User.find(id: args[:id])}
end
```

Originally I had:

```
field :userSingle, !types[Types::UserType] do
  resolve -> (obj, args, ctx) {User.find(id: args[:id])}
end
```

Same issue. If I take out the id: same issue. Also the same issue with:

```
  field :userSingle, !types[Types::UserType] do
    resolve -> (obj, args, ctx) {
    argument :first_name, !types.String
    argument :id, types.ID
      user = User.find_by(
        id: args[:id],
        first_name: args[:first_name])
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 7):

You could create a `user_type.rb` file with the following:

```
class Types::UserType < Types::BaseObject
  description "A user object"

  field :id, Integer, null: false
  field :first_name, String, null: false
end
```

Then have the following in `query_type.rb` file:

```
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    ...

    # User query
    field :user, UserType, null: true do
      description "Find a user by first_name"
      argument :first_name, String, required: true
    end
    def user(first_name:)
      User.find_by(first_name: first_name)
    end
  end
end
```

With all this in place, the query should then look like this:

```
{
  user(first_name: "name") {
    id
    firstName: first_name
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Instead of, !types[Types::UserType] in query_type file to 
field :userSingle do 
  type Types::UserType
  argument
  resolve
  ..
end